# params does not contain POST Body in Elixir / Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I try to build a very simple REST API. It does not include a database or models.

Here's my router:

```
defmodule Zentonies.Router do
  use Zentonies.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/v1/events/", Zentonies do
    pipe_through :api
    post "/call", PageController, :call
  end

end
```

Here is the Controller:

```
defmodule Zentonies.PageController do
  require Logger
  import Joken
  use Zentonies.Web, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "index.html"
  end

  def call(conn, params) do
    Logger.debug inspect(params)
    conn
    |> put_status(200)
    |> text("Response.")
  end
end
```

Now, if I HTTP POST to this endpoint, `inspect(params)` does not return the JSON body of my POST request. Instead it returns the `:call`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide the POST request you are making?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `call/2` function is [defined by Phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/7fd784a8fe92798fd212c49d1d114ec99e65693c/lib/phoenix/controller/pipeline.ex#L87-L104) for its own use to dispatch to the correct action in every Phoenix Controller. By creating a function with that name you're overriding the builtin functionality. You'll have to use a different name for the action. Check out the section "Controllers are plugs" in the documentation of [`Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline.html):

> ### Controllers are plugs
>
> Like routers, controllers are plugs, but they are wired to dispatch to a particular function which is called an action.
>
> For example, the route:
>
> ```
> get "/users/:id", UserController, :show
> ```
>
> will invoke `UserController` as a plug:
>
> ```
> UserController.call(conn, :show)
> ```
>
> which will trigger the plug pipeline and which will eventually invoke the inner action plug that dispatches to the `show/2` function in the `UserController`.